# Unable to delete session at times

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have below to handle logout and display information in the header to show after logout. But sometimes, it doesn't work. I suspect whether it is good to write this code to handle. Do you have any ideas? Please help

```
public function logout(){
         $this->nativesession->delete('user');
         redirect(base_url()); }
```

In header section of the php page:

```
<?php $usr = $this->nativesession->get('user');
      if(!isset($usr) || empty($usr) || $usr["username"]==null) {
                // show login button
           }
```

Comment: try this,  $this->session->sess_destroy();

Answer (score 1):

Logout Function:

```
 public function logout()
     {

        // Removing session data
       $this->session->sess_destroy();

        redirect('users/home');
    }
```

Add In Header befor html tag:

```
<?php
if ($this->session->userdata['admin']!='admin' ) {

redirect('login');
}
?>
```

Comment: Please include more details into your answer. If you are not sure if it will work, consider adding this as a comment instead. Thank you.